# What is the minimum set of hypotheses which the present physics is based on?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematics, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

Based on nowadays human understanding, what are the most fundamental hypotheses or principles in present physics which could deduce all other formula/theorem/details/applications?

Comment: I don't believe there are any.  Its known that relativity is incomplete on small distance scales, and quantum mechanics is incomplete at high energy levels.  Unifying these is the search for quantum gravity, and it is ongoing.

Comment: To paraphrase Feynman: The outline of the basic atomic model. You should get to most areas of physics  from there, eventually.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94560/2451 and links therein.

Comment: How about the minimum set of hypotheses nowadays physical theory is based on? I think there should be one which could deduce the "known" physics at present.