# Can the fundamental laws of Physics be formalized as axioms written in First Order Logic (FOL), or any other logical system for that matter?

Tags: mathematical-physics, laws-of-physics

Is it possible to state any fundamental law in Physics as an axiom written in [First Order Logic (FOL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), or any other logical system (and semantic interpretation) for that matter?

---

EDIT: in a way that other non-fundamental laws can be deduced as theorems from these axioms by applying inference rules.

Comment: Sure.  My logical language has one variable, namely $x$, one predicate, namely $P(x)$, and one axiom, namely "for all $x$, $P(x)$".  My semantic interpretation is that $x$ represents a physical system and $P(x)$ represents the statement "Newton's Laws apply to $x$".  I've just written all of Newtonian mechanics as an axiom-plus-semantic-interpretation in first order logic.  Perhaps this clarifies the downvote (which did not come from me).

Comment: This is an interesting question, that someone thought to oversimplify ad absurdum. I'd like to see a proper answer

Comment: @WillO, in your example, how would you go about proving new theorems from that axiom? (check out the edit to the question)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87239/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @xwb:  I would add some constant symbols to my language, semantically interpret those constant symbols as representing some specific physical situations, and then from the axiom "for all $x$, $P(x)$" I would deduce the theorems $P(c_1),P(c_2),P(c_3)...$.  This doesn't seem to be getting any more interesting.

Comment: One should not forget that the mathematics may be treated rigorosly, but that it's an important part of a physical law to specify the meaning of the physical entities in it (like: "x is the position of a particle"), and this is something entirely remote from axiomatization.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if such an axiomatization is possible, because axiomatizing real numbers is already impossible to do in a first order manner, as the first order axiomatization of the real is the same as for any of the ultrapower extensions of the real (the first-order axioms of $\mathbb{R}$ are the same as the first-order axioms of $^*\mathbb{R}$, for instance. I think they're just the axioms of $\mathbb{Q}$ overall).

First-order axiomatizations have been done for some theories, such as special relativity. There are many axiom systems, but here is one for instance, from [Andréka et al](http://file:///C:/Users/Slereah/Downloads/lstsamples.pdf).

The list of symbols, beyond the set theory symbols, is the following :

- $\mathsf{B}$ (bodies), $\mathsf{Ob}$ (observers), $\mathsf{Ph}$ (photons) and $\mathsf{F}$ (field) are unary relation symbols, to be used in contexts such as $\mathsf{B}(x)$ to signify $x$ is a body. We can also use those as sets, so that $x \in \mathsf{B} \leftrightarrow \mathsf{B}(x)$. We also have the relation that both observers and photons are bodies : $\mathsf{Ob}, \mathsf{Ph} \subset \mathsf{B}$
- The usual algebraic symbols $+$, $-$, $\times$, $/$ and $<$, with the usual meanings.
- For an $n$-dimensional spacetime, an $(n + 2)$-ary symbol $\mathsf{W}$, signifying that if $\mathsf{W}(x,y,z_1, z_2, ..., z_n)$, then the observer $x$ observes the body $y$ at coordinates $z^\mu$.

A few definitions :

- $^n\mathsf{F}$ is the set of $n$-tuples of $\mathsf{F}$. It has the structure of a vector space, with the usual axioms.
- The slope of a vector is defined by $$\mathsf{slope}(v) = (v_2^2 + v_3^2 + ... + v_n^2) / v_1^2$$if $v_1 \neq 0$, and the symbol $\mathsf{slope}(v) = \infty$ otherwise.
- The set of lines is defined by $$\mathsf{Lines} = \left\{ \{ q + \lambda v | \lambda \in \mathsf{F} \} | q, v \in {}^n\mathsf{F}, v \neq 0 \right\}$$(so that a single line is the set of points in ${}^n\mathsf{F}$ satisfying that condition for every $\lambda$ and a given origin $q$ and direction $v$)
- The slope of a line $\ell \in \mathsf{Lines}$ is defined by $$\forall p, q \in \ell, p \neq q, \mathsf{slope}(\ell) = \mathsf{slope}(p - q)$$
- The trace of a body $b \in \mathsf{B}$ given an observer $m \in \mathsf{Ob}$ is the set of coordinates at which $m$ sees $b$. $$\mathsf{tr}_m(b) = \{ p \in {}^n\mathsf{F} | \mathsf{W}(m, b, p) \}$$
- Inversely, an event at $p$ seen by an observer $m$ is the set of all bodies seen by $m$ at the coordinates $p$. $$\mathsf{ev}_m(p) = \left\{ b \in \mathsf{B} | \mathsf{W}(m, b, p) \right\}$$
- And finally, the speed of a body is the slope of its trace.$$\mathsf{speed}_m (b) = \mathsf{slope}(\mathsf{tr}_m(b))$$

With all these definitions, here's the list of axioms :

1. **AxSelf** : Every body sees itself as stationary at the origin. $$\mathsf{tr}_m(m) = \{ \langle t, 0, ..., 0 \rangle | t \in \mathsf{F} \}$$or, equivalently, $$\forall m, p, \left( (\mathsf{Ob}(m) \wedge \mathsf{F}(p_1)) \rightarrow [\mathsf{W}(m, m, p) \leftrightarrow (p_2 = 0 \wedge ... \wedge p_n = 0)]) \right)$$
2. **AxPh** : The trace of a photon always has slope $1$ (the speed of light is constant for all observers)$$\forall m \in \mathsf{Ob}, \left\{ \mathsf{tr}_m(\mathsf{ph}) 
    | \mathsf{ph} \in \mathsf{Ph} \right\} = \left\{ \ell \in \mathsf{Lines} | \mathsf{slope}(\ell) = 1 \right\}$$or, equivalently, $$\forall m, \forall p, q \in {}^n\mathsf{F}, \left( \mathsf{Ob}(m) \right [\exists \mathsf{ph} (\mathsf{Ph}(\mathsf{ph} \wedge \mathsf{W}(m, \mathsf{ph}, p) \wedge \mathsf{W}(m, \mathsf{ph}, q)) \leftrightarrow (p_1 - q_1)^2 = (p_2 - q_2)^2 + ... + (p_n - q_n)^2])$$
3. Observers see the same bodies.$$\{ \mathsf{ev}_m(p) | p \in {}^n\mathsf{F} \} = \{ \mathsf{ev}_k(p) | p \in {}^n\mathsf{F} \}$$or, equivalently, $$\forall m, k, \forall p \in {}^n\mathsf{F}, \exists q \in {}^n\mathsf{F}, ( (\mathsf{Ob}(m) \wedge \mathsf{Ob}(k)) \rightarrow \forall b \in \mathsf{B}, [\mathsf{W}(m, b, p) \leftrightarrow \mathsf{W}(k, b, q)] )$$

Along with the axioms of a field, these form a basic first-order  axiomatization of special relativity. A bit more robust axiomatization uses the additional definition of the worldview transformation (going from the coordinates of one observer to another)

$$\mathsf{f}_{mk} = \left\{ \langle p, q \rangle | \mathsf{ev}_m(p) = \mathsf{ev}_k(q) \wedge \mathsf{ev}_k(q) \neq \varnothing \wedge p, q \in {}^n\mathsf{F}  \right\}$$

This is basically the Poincaré transformation from observer $m$ to $k$, for which you can show $\mathsf{ev}_m(p) = \mathsf{ev}_k(\mathsf{f}_{mk}(p))$. Then you can add the axiom :

4. **AxSym** : The effects of time dilation are symmetric.$$\forall m, k, \forall p, q \in {}^n\mathsf{F}, (\mathsf{Ob}(m) \wedge \mathsf{Ob}(k)) \rightarrow \| \mathsf{f}_{mk}(p)_1 - \mathsf{f}_{mk}(q)_1 \| = \| \mathsf{f}_{km}(p)_1 - \mathsf{f}_{km}(q)_1 \|$$

This is not the only axiomatization of special relativity, nor the best (in particular, all observers are straight lines in this). But it's an example of a first-order axiomatization of a physical theory.

I don't think this will give great results, since as I've mentionned, you can't use real numbers here. Everything will be fairly awkward and something as basic as a square root will be beyond our usage. But it is something you can do, at least. I'm not aware of any such other first-order axiomatization for other theories (though I'm aware of an axiomatization of classical mechanics based on Hilbert's axioms, but this is not first order).

Comment: I edited the title question so that other logical systems might be used if FOL falls short.

Comment: For other logical system, see here : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388849/are-certain-fields-of-physics-axiomatized/388864#388864