How does the Nature behave exactly like what mathematical tools tell us?
As we progress in studying physics, there are a lot of mathematical tools that we use to order to describe physics phenomena, like how electromagnetic waves travel in space, falling bodies under gravitational field or the motion of fluids.
All of these phenomena are described under the same axioms and the same rules, but how do we know that nature will behave according to what the mathematical rules tell us? How do we know that nature will act in accordance to our formulas and principles?

To be succinct, it's the other way round. We define the rules according to our observations in nature. If they don't describe natural phenomena accurately, we revise them. A law is no longer when it is found it doesn't apply to reality.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44196/

If OP is asking about theories not rooted in observations, then the question seems opinion-based. Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94560/2451 and links therein.

@Qmechanic Could you please explain how it's a duplicate? I may be missing something but it seems that your linked question is somewhat more specific while Mason's question is quite general.
